# Pop-up video showing during page load on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am trying to add a pop-up video on the home page of a website using jquery smartmodal plugin using the cookies to show the video only once per user.

It is having one problem, whenever I try to reload the page than the video shows on top while loading of page after that it disappears. I don't want the video to show during page load.

How can i do this ?

Comment: call your function on 

$(window).load(function(){
    //Call Your Plugin 
})

right now it's on ready function

Answer (score 0):

just call your function after DOM is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.smartModal();
})
```

and wrap your video in a wrapper div and hide it with css like

```
<div style="display:none;">
    {your video html}
</div>
```

right now is called when your page starts loading.

Comment: I tried it but i am still able to see the video on top of page while page loads.

Comment: wrap your video in a wrapper and hide it with css, see updated answer